# How to access nested JSON objects/arrays with 'lowdb'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am wondering how to access a nested JSON array/object with `lowdb` syntax?!

Basically i have this structure as `lowdb` file:

```
{
  "57": {
    "hour": [],
    "day": [],
    "week": [],
    "month": []
  },
  "58": {
    "hour": [],
    "day": [],
    "week": [],
    "month": []
  }
}
```

Now i want to fill the arrays dynamically, but i am not able to push any values into...

My code:

```
const low       = require('lowdb');
const FileSync  = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter   = new FileSync('myFile.json')
const db        = low(adapter);

....

// add new object
db.set("57", { hour: [], day: [], week: [], month: [] }).write();

console.log(db.get('57').value().hour[0]); // prints ofc 'undefined'
console.log(db.get('57').value().hour);   // prints [] which is correct

// both commands are not working  | for test just push a single item
// later the item will be another object 
// db.get('57').value().hour.push('item').write();
// db.get('57').hour.push('item').write();


// if copying first it's working well
var tmp = db.get('57').value().hour;
tmp.push('item');
console.log(tmp); // outputs [ 'item' ]
```

I got the feeling that this is not possible with lowdb due to the nested structure. If possible, can somebody tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

OK, i helped myself in a different way.

My solution is, get the whole object from `lowdb` and copy it to local variables:

```
let arrayHour   = db.get(item.ITEM_ID).value().hour;
let arrayDay    = db.get(item.ITEM_ID).value().day;
let arrayWeek   = db.get(item.ITEM_ID).value().week;
let arrayMonth  = db.get(item.ITEM_ID).value().month;
```

Then edit the data in every way i need to:

```
// remove obsolete value
if (arrayHour.length >= 6)
  arrayHour.splice(0, 1);

if (arrayDay.length >= 24)
  arrayDay.splice(0, 1);

if (arrayWeek.length >= 7)
  arrayWeek.splice(0, 1);

if (arrayMonth.length >= 30)
  arrayMonth.splice(0, 1);

...

// add new values
arrayHour.push({name: item.NAME_DE, smkurs: item.SMKURS, ts: item.TS});

...
```

And then push the whole collection back into `lowdb`

```
// put the values back
db.get(item.ITEM_ID).push({"hour": arrayHour, "day": arrayDay, "week": arrayWeek, "month": arrayMonth}).write();
```

This is working well and `lowdb` doesnt have to handle nested objects.